# Can't center horizontally 'float' cells with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to save my pandas dataframe as excel file with `df.to_excel()` using `xlsxwriter` engine. I am trying to format header and rows with two different formats:

```py
workbook = writer.book
header_format = workbook.add_format({
   'bold' : True,
   'valign' : 'vcenter',
   'align' : 'center',
   'bg_color' : '#D7E4BC',
   'border' : 1
})

cell_format = workbook.add_format({
   'valign' :  'center',
   'align' : 'center',
   'border' : 1
})

#Add header formatting
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
   worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)

#Add row formatting
worksheet.conditional_formatting(1, 0, df.shape[0], df.shape[1], {'type' : 'no_blanks', 'format' : cell_format})
```

I don't know why, but only cells with float values aren't being centered horizontally. I would like to know how to center them too (if possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a conditional format to set alignment in Excel. From the XlsxWriter [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html#conditional-format-options):

> **Note**
> In Excel, a conditional format is superimposed over the existing cell format and not all cell format properties can be modified. Properties that cannot be modified in a conditional format are font name, font size, superscript and subscript, diagonal borders, all alignment properties and all protection properties.

If you want to add formatting to the cells of the dataframe you will probably need to do it cell by cell, like you did for the header.

Comment: Hmm, but i can't format cells without using `write()`, right? I am using pandas so i don't know what can be done.